# Servers Vs Ip address

Tags: hosting

When I say,

1000 domains are hosted on the same server.

Does it means that 1000 domains are hosted on the same IP address?

Comment: In short, no it doesn't.

Comment: Am confused..Can someone explain me this..??

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You configure the server software to correlate the host name to the right service files.  This applies to FTP/WWW, etc.

Comment: But this isn't necessarily true - are you saying one physical server can't handle multiple IPs?

Comment: No, I'm not.  Obviously you can multiple IPs with their own sites or even same sites shared between IPs.  But the gist of the question seems to be is is possible to have several domains all point to the same IP address.  In which case the answer is yes.

Comment: Hmm, I'm reading the question as "If we know there are 1000 domains on a given server, does this mean they will all have the same IP address?", in which case the answer is no, not necessarily.

Comment: @Codeobsession - I think you need to clarify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A server can host either *virtually* by use of the same IP address with different host headers (example.com, sample.com, sub.sample.com), through the use of multiple IPs bound to the server, *or* a combination of both.

So to answer your question, *no*, having 1000 domains hosted on the same IP address doesn't mean that they have the same IP address.  However, it is possible given the configuration of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, yes.

There is nothing stopping you from installing another NIC and having another IP address on the machine, but typically, 1000 domains hosted on the same server will be accessible using the same IP address.

Web servers use the host header to determine which site to load when many sites are configured to use the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, with [name based virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based), a feature introduced in HTTP 1.1.  It causes some problems with really old (corporate) proxies that pretend to only speak HTTP 1.0 and there are SSL related issues, so in general it's not the optimum solution.